# CMake Error include dir 'include' does not exist relative

Tags: ros, catkin-make, include, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros kinetic on ubuntu 16.04

After setting up the environment and installing all dependencies using rosdep from the root I am running catkin_make and getting error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:302 (message):
  catkin_package() include dir 'include' does not exist relative to
  '/home/cerlab/Documents/depowder_summer_2018/src/cam_kinect'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  cam_kinect/CMakeLists.txt:83 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/cerlab/Documents/depowder_summer_2018/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/cerlab/Documents/depowder_summer_2018/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:3118: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

The CMakeLists.txt file for my cam_kinect starting at line **80** is as follows:

```
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES cam_kinect
 CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs roslib message_runtime
 DEPENDS Boost PCL
)
```

Also my ros environment:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/cerlab/Documents/depowder_summer_2018/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/cerlab/Documents/depowder_summer_2018/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295069/cmake-error-include-dir-%27include%27-does-not-exist-relative/) by [av3006](https://answers.ros.org/users/35894/av3006/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on 2018-06-22**:
Please could you please provide the full CMakeLists.txt, and the output of "ls -l" from your package ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think we already know what causes this: there is no `include` directory in the package dir.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yemre](https://answers.ros.org/users/44127/yemre/) on 2019-07-21**:
Just to get this question "answered", @gvdhoorn has already provided the answer so I will re-post here:

> I think we already know what causes this: there is no `include` directory in the package dir.